# Getting text From UITextView and email It straight to an email?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to find a way that after a button is pressed, text is taken from a UITextView and emailed straight to a specific email. 
Is there an easy way to do this?
Please note i'm new to programming.

Comment: *Please not I would like to be able to send it through an email account set up to handle these messages. So not to use the users own email.

Answer (score 0):

You cant send an email without launching the iOS mail client 'MFMailComposeViewController'. You could try creating an API call that would perform this for you, you would just send the text to this call and the server would send an email on your behalf.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention, I was planning on the text being sent through an email account set up to handle these. So not the users own email.

Comment: you will need to use a server to do this.Look at `Parse` if you do not have access to a server.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial [Send email tutorial ios8 swift](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/send-email-tutorial-ios8-swift)

You are new ios developer so is a good idea follow and understand a tutorial.